# When an automorphism of $k[[x,y]]$ is also an automorphism of $k[x,y]$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, power-series

After asking [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240957/automorphisms-of-kx-y-which-are-also-automorphisms-of-kx-y), I would like to generalize it a little:

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero.
A $k$-automorphism of $k[[x,y]]$ was described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2225740/the-group-of-k-automorphisms-of-kx-y-k-is-a-field):
$f: (x,y) \mapsto (A,B)$ is a $k$-automorphism of $k[[x,y]]$ if and only if $A,B$ are power series with no constant term whose linear parts are linearly independent.

> When a given $k$-automorphism $f:(x,y) \mapsto (A,B)$ of $k[[x,y]]$ is also an automorphism of $k[x,y]$?

More precisely, what additional conditions are needed in order to answer my question positively?

My question does not have a uniqe answer; for example:
(1) In [the above mentioned question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240957/automorphisms-of-kx-y-which-are-also-automorphisms-of-kx-y) we have seen that if $f$ is of finite order and $A,B \in k[x,y]$, then $f$ is also an automorphism of $k[x,y]$.
(2) I wonder if the following condition is sufficient: $f$ is of finite order (apriori, we do not know if $A,B \in k[x,y]$) and there exists $T \subseteq k[x,y]$ such that $T$ is dense in $k[[x,y]]$ and invariant under $f$, namely $f(T) \subseteq T$. Notice that if $T=k[x,y]$, then we arrive at the first example (1), so we better assume that $T \subsetneq k[x,y]$ if we wish to get a new condition.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think you are being loose. If $A,B$ are not in $k[x,y]$, then $f$ does not even induce an endomorphism of $k[x,y]$, let alone an automorphism. So, you must at the very least assume that.

Comment: Good comment. I agree that it is necessary that $A,B \in k[x,y]$, but I do not wish to assume this, but to obtain this from other conditions. (I am sorry for not writing this explicitly).

Comment: On the other hand, I do not mind to assume that $f$ is of finite order.