# $k$-automorphisms of $k[[x]]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, power-series

Let $k$ be a field. I have two questions about the formal power series $k[[x]]$.

> 1. How to determine elements in $\mathrm{Aut}(k[[x]])$?
> 2. How to determine elements in this set:$$\{f\in k[[x]]: \exists g\in k[[x]] \text{ s.t. } f(g(x))=g(f(x))=x\}$$

It seems these two questions are related. Could you provide some help? Thanks!

Comment: For question two: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Composition_inverse

Comment: For question one: therefore the automorphisms of $(k[[x]])$ are precisely those ring endomorphisms that send $x$ to one of these compositionally invertible elements

Comment: Abstract duplicate of [The group of $k$-automorphisms of $k[[x,y]]$, $k$ is a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2225740/the-group-of-k-automorphisms-of-kx-y-k-is-a-field)

Comment: So the 3 steps are: any $k$-automorphism sends $x$ to a non-unit, in $xk[[x]]$, so it  is continuous determined by where it sends $x$, for being surjective it must not be in $x^2k[[x]]$, and any such element of $xk[[x]]-x^2k[[x]]$ has a compositional inverse.